# Create 2 table ids, the second restarts when the first increments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CASES]
(
    [CASE_ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [CASE_SECTION] INT NOT NULL,
    [CASE_DATA] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
)
```

I want `CASE_SECTION` to increment based on whether the `CASE_ID` has changed.

Example:

```
CASE_ID  CASE_SECTION  CASE_DATA
---------------------------------------------
1        1             'FROG ATE THE FLY'
1        2             'FROG SAT ON LOG'
2        1             'CHEETAH CHEATAXED'
3        1             'BLUE CHEESE STINKS'
```

Basically, I want to do something similar to using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_ID)` as the `CASE_DATA` is inserted into the table.

Is there a way I can set the table up so that `CASE_SECTION` increments like this by default when data is inserted?

Comment: I have a feeling you don't really want to use ROW_NUMBER you are instead hoping to have this auto increment by CASE_ID. There is no easy way to do that.

Comment: How about a trigger. setting inserted.case_section = (select MAX(CASE_SECTION)+1 from cases c where c.case_id=inserted.case_id). Note this assumes a single line insert.

Comment: @SeanLange Is there a hard way?

Comment: @KeithL Unfortunately, this db can't have triggers due to some 3rd party software.  But I like the idea!

Comment: Sure there is a hard way. It requires something along the lines of what @KeithL suggested. This type of approach is also extremely brittle. I would suggest that perhaps you need an entirely different approach to whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm trying an approach to automated testing on a business report.  Based on some situations, a test case may have multiple rows of data that need to be checked so I wanted to group those cases using a CASE_SECTION.  It's not a huge problem, I can just hard code the CASE_SECTION into the test cases.  I just though there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: Are you able to add new columns to the table?

Comment: @TabAlleman  The table is in design at the moment, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rownumber:

```
Select row_number() over(partition by case_id order by case_data) as case_section, * from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add either an IDENTITY or InsertedDateTime column to the table, you can use that to make `Case_Section` a computed column that uses row_number() partitioned by `case_id`.

Another poster suggested this, but if you order by case_data or any other column that isn't guaranteed to be ordinal, you run the risk that the value will move around as data is inserted and changes the order of the rows.

If your computation does `row_number() over(partition by case_id order by [ColumnThatIncreasesWithEachInsert])` then the values will be stable over time.

Comment: @TabAllerman I'm running into a syntax error when I try to use row_number for the computed column.  I saw a couple of comments on other questions which said that windowing functions and aggregate functions can't be used for computed columns.